# Adding charaters to a string in specified places - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple python action that I want to take. I have a string. something like `2364968438`. I want to take that string that I have and add a `-` between specific places in the string to make it look like a phone number. something like this `236-496-8438` within my django/python project. I know i am going to have to slice the string into parts but I am having trouble with it.

I want to create a method within the views.py file that will take a string and split it as well as apply the changes..

```
def numberfy(request, number): 
    phone = 
    #code that splits the number and adds hyphen goes here
    return phone
```

Does it matter if it is a string or integer?

Comment: an integer cannot be saved like this, but what matters is where you want to apply this, in a template ? in a model ? from a form ? Could you provide some code to set the context ?

Comment: I want to create a method within the views.py file that will take a string and split it as well as apply the changes.. `def numberfy(request, number): phone = #code that splits the number and adds hyphen goes here# return phone` This is something that it would look like. @PRMoureu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splice it and join it (if your input is already validated):

```
def dashify(num):
    s = str(num)
    return '-'.join([s[:3], s[3:6], s[6:]])
```

For example:

```
>>> dashify(2364968438)
'236-496-8438'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way :)

```
myStr = '5141234567'

myNumber = myStr[:3] + '-' + myStr[:3] + '-' + myStr[:4]

print myNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is straightforward :

```
def format_number(number):
    number = str(number)
    groups = number[:3], number[3:6], number[6:]
    return "-".join(groups)

print(format_number("2364968438"))
# -> 236-496-8438
```